# remove UIView subview based on tag?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am creating a view like this:

```
UILabel *qty = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
qty.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
qty.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@" Qty: %@", currentQty];
qty.alpha = 0.5;
[qty setTag:999];
[self.view addSubview:qty];
[qty release];
```

This can happen multiple times in this view controller so before I create a new view like this I want to remove any that might exist with this tag, I am trying this:

```
UIView *removeView  = [self.view viewWithTag:999];
[removeView removeFromSuperview];
```

This is not working for some reason, anyone see my problem here?

I guess i could loop through all the views and check the tag but would rather have a more elegant and direct solution.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is the issue that you're possibly only removing one view of several?  Try this:

```
UIView *removeView;
while((removeView = [self.view viewWithTag:999]) != nil) {
    [removeView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

If there's only one view that's getting created/tagged/removed, you also might consider just adding a property to track that view, and writing:

```
[self.subView removeFromSuperview];
self.subView = qty;
```